# Filtering rows based on different date requirements

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns consisting of a site ID, the date of a sample and a measured value. Here is a theoretical dataset.

```
Dates <- data.frame(c(as.Date("2008-7-1"),
rep(as.Date("2008-3-1"), times = 4) , 
              rep(as.Date("2008-9-1"), times = 4),
                as.Date("2008-9-8")))
Sites <- as.data.frame(as.factor(c("Site1",rep(c("Site1","Site2","Site3","Site4"), 2),
                 "Site1")))
Values <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:50, 5*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Dataframe <- cbind(Dates,Sites,Values)
colnames(Dataframe) <- c("date","site","value")
```

I am screening out specific samples that do not match certain criteria.

**Firstly**, I would like to only select spring and autumn samples. So I would like to select sites between March-May and September-November, meaning the first row in the dataframe would be removed. Is there a better way than the following:

```
library(dplyr)
Season_sequence <- c(seq(as.Date("2008-3-1"), 
                    as.Date("2008-5-31"), by="days"),
                 seq(as.Date("2008-9-1"), 
                     as.Date("2008-11-30"), by="days"))

`%datein%` <- function(x,y) (x %in% y) 

Season_removed <- Dataframe %>%
filter(date %datein% Season_sequence)
```

This works but if I have samples over several years I am not sure how to quickly create a sequence to match this.

**Secondly**, I do not want two samples from a specific site within a particular season (i.e. I do not want any replicate samples), meaning that the last row in the dataframe would be removed. I am not sure how to start with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *first* problem, you can create a column for your month (independent from the year) and select on that one (here, converted into numeric but you could keep the plain word selection too).
For the *second* problem, you can use `disctinct`:

```
Dataframe %>% 
  mutate(month = as.numeric(format(date, '%m'))) %>%
  filter(month %in% c(3,4,5,9,10,11)) %>%
  distinct(month, site)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is brilliant and very nearly there! But rather than each site being distinct, is there a way of creating a site/season combination ID and use distinct for this? I.e. I would like to keep the spring and autumn sample for all sites.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the months function to subset:

```
 library(dplyr)
`%datein%` <- function(x,y) (x %in% y) 
 seasons<-c("March", "April", "May", "September", "October", "November")
 Season <- Dataframe %>%
 filter(months(Dataframe$date) %datein% seasons)
```

This will allow to select the same month(s) across multiple years.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have just edited this so that rows are removed based on the months function you put in.